# Unity Custom NavMesh obstacle for terrain trees?

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, unity3d-terrain

I have a terrain with trees on it that is baked into the NavMesh. The NavMesh automatically creates a barrier around the trees, but it seems to be based around the model, not the collider. Since I only want the AI to dodge the trunk of the tree, not the branches, how can I create a custom NavMesh obstacle for the trees? I tried adding a NavMesh obstacle to the tree, but it didn't do anything. Here's a screenshot showing what I mean:

[image: screenshot]

Basically, that's too big of a barrier, I want it to be smaller and be able to set a custom NavMesh obstacle on it.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure there was option to change navmesh build source from mesh to collider but I cannot find it, I suppose it has been removed from inspector but you can still generate your navmesh from script like that:

```
Bounds bounds = new Bounds(Vector3.zero, new Vector3(200,20,200);
List<NavMeshBuildSource> sources = new List<NavMeshBuildSource>();        
NavMeshBuilder.CollectSources( bounds, LayerMask.GetMask("Default"),NavMeshCollectGeometry.PhysicsColliders,0, new List<NavMeshBuildMarkup>(), sources );
NavMeshData data = NavMeshBuilder.BuildNavMeshData( NavMesh.GetSettingsByID( 0 ), sources, bounds, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity );        
NavMesh.RemoveAllNavMeshData();
NavMesh.AddNavMeshData( data );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to smaller barrier you can change your agent size and re-bake. [image: Here is the agent size settings]

And if you want modify the obstacles, you can use navmesh modifier and you can assign as walkable area so navmesh will be ignore this obstacle when baking.
https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/class-NavMeshModifier.html